# PHP: fopen failed "HTTP Request Failed", but response header has a status code 200

Tags: php, http, proxy, fopen

I have a PHP script, that should connect to a proxy, chosen from a proxy list and download a file. Some of the proxies (out of 200-400 working ones) work perfectly, but others don't, and I cannot find out why.

Here the code that connects through the proxy:

```
    $proxy = determine_proxy ($proxyList);
 $proxyString = 'tcp://' . $proxy['ip'] . ':' . $proxy['port'];

 $userAgent = $userAgents [rand (0, $agentsCount - 1)];

 // set up our headers
 $hdrs = array( 'http' => array(
     'method' => "GET",
     'header'=> "Host: www.example.net\r\n" .
      // "User-Agent: $userAgent\r\n" .
      "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" .
      "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n" .
      "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n" . 
      "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n" .
      "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n" .
  "Referer: http://$url",     // Setting the http-referer
     'proxy' => "$proxyString",
     'request_fulluri' => true
     )
 );

 echo "Using proxy: "; print_r ($proxy); echo '<br>';

 $context = stream_context_create ($hdrs);  // set up the context

 $timeout = 3;
 $oldTimeout = ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $timeout);
 $oldAgent = ini_set ('user_agent', $userAgent);

 $fp = fopen ("http://www.example.net$file", 'r', false, $context); // open the file

 if (!$fp) {
  echo 'fopen failed! Skipping this proxy for now...<br>';
  print_r ($http_response_header); echo '<br />';
  unset ($http_response_header);
  flush(); @ob_flush();
  ini_set ('user_agent', $oldAgent);
  ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $oldTimeout);
  continue;
 }

 print_r ($http_response_header); echo '<br />';
 unset ($http_response_header);
```

The bizarre thing is that the response header for the failed tries is sometimes empty, and sometimes it's the following:

```
   Array (
 [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 [1] => Server: falcon
 [2] => Date: Sun, 16 Jan 2011 14:06:37 GMT
 [3] => Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent
 [4] => Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
 [5] => Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.torrent"
 [6] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
 [7] => Connection: close
)
```

And sometimes, it's this:

```
   Array ( 
 [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK 
 [1] => Server: falcon 
 [2] => Date: Sun, 16 Jan 2011 14:06:47 GMT 
 [3] => Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent 
 [4] => Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
 [5] => Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example2.torrent" 
 [6] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent 
 [7] => X-Cache: MISS from proxy 
 [8] => Proxy-Connection: close
)
```

This is a response header from a ***successful*** attempt:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: falcon
Date: Fri, 21 Jan 2011 18:53:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example3.torrent"
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Cache: MISS from www.example.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from www.example.com:3128
Via: 1.0 www.example.com (squid/3.0.STABLE23-BZR)
Proxy-Connection: close
```

I am setting the user agent to be a valid user agent string, I have checked allow_url_fopen and it is set to On.

From RFC-2616, section 10:

> 200 OK
>
> The request has succeeded. The
>   information returned with the response
>   is dependent on the method used in the
>   request, for example:
>
> GET an entity corresponding to the
>   requested resource is sent in the
>   response;

How is it possible, that the server via the proxy returns a status of 200, and still fopen fails? Does anybody have an idea about the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the fact, that I was setting a socket timeout that in some cases was too low for fopen to manage and download all the data. After the timeout period has gone and fopen still hadn't downloaded the data, it returned FALSE and threw an "HTTP reqeust failed" error.

Comment: Since you've answered your own question, please mark the answer as "Accepted". This will stop the question showing up in the list of unanswered questions, and will also help anyone who finds this page in the future looking for a similar answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have the habit of leaving it open for a few days to allow for others to answer it (perhaps in a better way).

Answer (score 0):

the server reported 200 OK , but the proxy still didn't know where to forward this data to , so you got a Request Failed ...

try using the VIA header

Comment: But I also get the exact same header (the first example in my question) in occasions, in which the download has succeeded. How is that possible? And what to you mean by "the proxy still didn't know where to forward this data to"?

Comment: some (old) proxies might not send the datab back to you unless you tell them so (in some header which i don

Comment: Some (old) proxies don't know where to send the data unless you tell them so (by some header) but this might be untrue in your situation as you had successful downloads , try to "Proxy-Connection: close\r\n" .

Comment: I tried with Proxy-Connection: close, the result was the same. The weird thing is that in the response headers after the try fails, there is sometimes even a Content-Disposition header! I have tried to avoid CURL, but I guess I will have to try that as well.

Comment: I also looked at all the HTTP header request fields and I couldn't find one, that serves the purpose you describe (to tell the proxy where to forward the data).

Comment: try checking the headers the proxy sends to the remote server (listen to port 80 and let the proxy connect to it and paste the headers here) , do you use your own proxy ? does the proxies work with other systems (try using the proxy from chrome and check the headers chrome sends/receives by pressing ctrl+shift+j)

Comment: I am not using my own proxies - I use a list of several hundred proxies. I noticed the following response header from a SUCCESSFUL attempt (see last edit in my question).

Comment: in `$fp = fopen ("http://www.example.net$file", 'r', false, $context); // open the file` you are not connecting to the proxy , you are connecting directly to the website ..